# what is maximum value of $n/m + (50-n)/(100-m)$, where $0 \leq n \leq 50$, and $n \leq m \leq 100$

Tags: calculus, probability, contest-math

Ok, here is original question:

There are 100 candies, 50 of them are red, and 50 of them are blue. Then, we are going to distribute these candies into two boxes. Then how to distribute these candies so that another person can have largest probability to get red candies (that person will randomly selects a box, and randomly select a candy from that chosen box )

I am thinking using the following to address:
Prob(n, m) = 1/2 (n/m + (50-n)/(100-m)), where n is the number of red candies in the first box, and m is the total candies in the first box. So, I am thinking about calculate the largest value of Prob (n, m)

Calculate the maximum of $n/m + (50-n)/(100-m)$, where $1 \leq n \leq 50$, and $n \leq m \leq 100$).

3 conditions:

(1) $m$ and $n$ must be integers

(2) $1 \le n\le m \le99$

(3) $100-m \ge50-n$

Intuitively, when $n=1$, $m=1$, it will be the largest, but not quite sure why.

Comment: Ummm... why not $m=99.99999$?

Comment: are you limited to integers?  otherwise yeah,  getting m as close to 100 makes the second blow up

Comment: This has nothing to do with linear algebra.

Comment: It's undefined when $m=100.$ Are you sure the question isn't $m<100?$

Comment: And I agree with @ThomasAndrews

Comment: sorry, modified my questions. Mis-typed something

Comment: again, your last question still allows $m$ to be 100 or $0$, both of which are not allowed

Comment: Given a fixed $m$ find the value $n$ which satisfies the conditions.

Comment: and please don't edit it again...

Comment: yeah, I should say m is not allowed to set 100

Comment: please edit, but use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) so others don't have to edit it for you

Comment: post the original question, sorry for confusion!

Comment: did the question mention you cannot let one box be empty or something...

Comment: yes, that's right!

Comment: see this [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/libxg3je4b) for some intuition

Comment: the red line shows the probability for some fixed $n$ (showed there by $a$) as $m$ ($x$ there) varies. The part of the graph not shown is where the $a$ and $x$  (or $n$ and $m$) violate the conditions. The green line shows the probability when $n=m=1$ (or $x=a=1$). Try varying $a$ (or $n$) by moving the slider to see if it meets the green line. You will find it only meets for $a=x=1$ or $a=x=99$, which are equivalent cases.

Comment: Thank you for this graph!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We want to maximize $P=\dfrac nm+\dfrac{50-n}{100-m}$, this is a linear function of $n$, if written as
\[n\left(\frac1m-\frac1{100-m}\right)+\frac{50}{100-m}.\]
When $m\le50$, the coefficient of $n$ is $\dfrac1m-\dfrac1{100-m}\ge0$, so maximum of $P$ is at the maximum of $n$. In this case, $n=\min\{m,50\}=m$. Plug in to get
\[P=1+\frac{50-n}{100-n}=2-\frac{50}{100-n}.\]
Maximum of $P$ is clearly the minimum of $n$, so $m=n=1$.

When $m>50$, the coefficient of $n$ is $\dfrac1m-\dfrac1{100-m}<0$, so maximum of $P$ is at the minimum of $n$, which is $n=1$. Plug in to get
\[P=\frac1m+\frac{49}{100-m}.\]
Clearly this is a decreasing function of $m$, so its maximum is at the minimum of $m$. Therefore $m=50$, $n=1$ maximizes $P$.

In conclusion, we check the two cases,
\begin{align*}m=n=1&\implies P=\frac{148}{99}>1.\\[2pt]m=50,n=1&\implies P=1.\end{align*}
Hence, $P$ takes overall maximum $P_\max=\dfrac{148}{99}$ when $m=n=1$.

Comment: did you just mistyped? it should be $1/m - 1/(100-m)$, right?